# SSO:How to get array of groups in redmine ominiauth SAML plugin from the SAML respone?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, openam, redmine-plugins

Implementing SSO for redmine: Idp- OpenAM, SP-redmine (Ominiauth SAML plugin)

I want to get list of groups which are assigned to user in redmine_ominiauth_saml plugin but I can get just single group which is first on SAML response in groups assertion.

So is there any different configuration for array attribute:

Mapping of attributes for SP on OpenAM:

- groups=isMemberOf
- last_name=sn
- username=mail
- first_name=givenName
- email=mail

Mapping of attributes on Redmine:
"/opt/redmine/config/initializers/saml_3.0.rb"

```
:attribute_mapping              => {
    # How will we map attributes from SSO to redmine attribute
      :login      => 'extra.raw_info.username',
      :firstname  => 'extra.raw_info.first_name',
      :lastname   => 'extra.raw_info.last_name',
      :mail       => 'extra.raw_info.email',
      :isMemberOf => 'extra.raw_info.groups'
    }
```

SAML response contains attribute groups in array like this:

```
<saml:AttributeStatement>
                        <saml:Attribute Name="first_name">
                                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                                     xsi:type="xs:string"
                                                     >umesh</saml:AttributeValue>
                        </saml:Attribute>
                        <saml:Attribute Name="username">
                                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                                     xsi:type="xs:string"
                                                     >ubr@abc.com</saml:AttributeValue>
                        </saml:Attribute>
                        <saml:Attribute Name="email">
                                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                                     xsi:type="xs:string"
                                                     >ubr@abc.com</saml:AttributeValue>
                        </saml:Attribute>
                        <saml:Attribute Name="last_name">
                                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                                     xsi:type="xs:string"
                                                     >rajani</saml:AttributeValue>
                        </saml:Attribute>
                        <saml:Attribute Name="groups">
                                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                                     xsi:type="xs:string"
                                                     >cn=ABC,ou=groups,dc=abc,dc=opendj,dc=com</saml:AttributeValue>
                                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                                     xsi:type="xs:string"
                                                     >cn=XYZ,ou=groups,dc=abc,dc=opendj,dc=com</saml:AttributeValue>
                                <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                                                     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                                     xsi:type="xs:string"
                                                     >cn=YZQ,ou=groups,dc=abc,dc=opendj,dc=com</saml:AttributeValue>
                        </saml:Attribute>
                </saml:AttributeStatement>
```

I knew this code in SAML plugin gives me single group (code in ruby):
/opt/redmine/plugins/redmine_omniauth_saml/lib/redmine_omniauth_saml.rb

```
def user_attributes_from_saml(omniauth)

         HashWithIndifferentAccess.new.tap do |h|
          required_attribute_mapping.each do |symbol|
            key = configured_saml[:attribute_mapping][symbol]
              h[symbol] = key.split('.')                # Get an array with nested keys: name.first will return [name, first]
              .map {|x| [:[], x]}                     # Create pair elements being :[] symbol and the key
              .inject(omniauth) do |hash, params|     # For each key, apply method :[] with key as parameter
                hash.send(*params)
              end
             **print "key:value "+key+":" +h[symbol]**  # gives key value pair, first_name, group 'ABC' only leaves other group
          end
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually ruby-saml plugin is default retrun as attributes as single value.

We need to set as for multi value in ruby-saml plugin.

ruby-saml plugin have attributes.rb file.

Update the value of @@single_value_compatibility and set as "false"

Now you are getting full array of value.

Hope you issue will resolved.